# I need a cheat sheet for PACG

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

I have a "Pathfinder Adventure Card Game: Skull And Shackles" set.  One of my players is sick this week, so I've recruited a substitute.  We're partway through Adventure Deck 3.

I need to explain the rules of Pathfinder Adventure Card Game to my new player in a way that will bring him up to speed quickly.  Ideally I'd like to print out a cheat sheet.  I imagine it would say things like: "Here's the list of things you do in your turn" and "here's what happens when you reveal a card, display a card, recharge a card, discard a card, bury a card, banish a card".

I did some brief websearch and could not find a cheat sheet.  Does anyone know where I could find one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking for materials to help out with games, always check out boardgamegeek.com. In the case of your question, they have a downloadable 'rules summary and reference cards'

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/151007/pathfinder-adventure-card-game-skull-shackles-base

(I know link-only answers aren't great, but the question really seems to be looking for a link...)

Comment: Either I'm blind or the quoted section is not there now.